# Mouse move message for child window are intercepted by parent, how to get them in child window's callback

Tags: callback, cursor, mousemove, adobe-illustrator, windows-messages

I was writing an plugin of Adobe Illustrator. The Illustator UI has many non-modal dialogs (floating panels) in main window. I want to deal with the **WM_MOUSEMOVE** message of one panel. So I find the handle of the panel and use **SetWindowLongPtr()** to set a CALLBACK function of that panel, and use **SetCapture()** function to let it capture the mouse. But in the callback **WM_MOUSEMOVE** messages didn't come, however I use SPY++ to watch the panel and all **WM_MOUSEMOVE** messages were there. So I guess that the host application does something (maybe mouse hook?) to get the mouse messages and doesn't hand them to the panel's callback function.

What can I do to know where the host application intercepts the messages? It seems host will change the cursor when mouse moves to somewhere, how can I prevent it from setting the cursor?